# Local load balancing and using cloud services when needed

Tags: load-balancing, cloud-computing

Suppose a company has a set of web+data servers that are load balanced, but sometimes the application gets a burst that goes beyond server capabilities.

This would nicely mitigate the cost of cloud services to only use them when you actually need them. Otherwise in-house hardware suffices.

**Question**
Has anybody done load balancing of such bursts to cloud services? Is it at all possible? WHat would one have to think about to achieve such configuration?